# Code review - Transaction without begin try in procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, transactions

I'm doing a code review for a new procedure in sql
and i have two question please:

1. The commit transaction is encapsulated in the whole procedure - i think it should be only in the insert statement.
2. If there is a begin transaction, there should be also a error handling.

I am adding the code before

```
BEGIN   
DECLARE @paymentSpecificationId BIGINT ;
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SET @paymentSpecificationId = (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[PaymentSpecifications] 
    WHERE PaymentSpecificationGuid = @PaymentSpecificationGuid) ;

    IF(@paymentSpecificationId > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @paymentSpecificationId AS Results;
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        RETURN;
    END
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[PaymentSpecifications] 
    (
        [CurrencyBalanceId],
        [PaymentSpecificationGuid],
        [PaymentSpecificationTypeId],
        [ExternalId],
        [Reference],
        [ExternalOriginatorId],
        [EventTimestamp],
        [Created]
    )
    VALUES 
    (
        @CurrencyBalanceId,
        @PaymentSpecificationGuid,
        @PaymentSpecificationTypeId,
        @ExternalId,
        @Reference,
        @ExternalOriginatorId,
        @EventTimestamp,
        @Created
    )
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS Results;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

and the code after my suggestion fix

```
BEGIN   
    
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @paymentSpecificationId BIGINT ;
        
        SET @paymentSpecificationId = (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[PaymentSpecifications] 
        WHERE PaymentSpecificationGuid = @PaymentSpecificationGuid) ;

        IF(@paymentSpecificationId > 0)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @paymentSpecificationId AS Results;
            RETURN;
        END
        
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[PaymentSpecifications] 
            (
                [CurrencyBalanceId],
                [PaymentSpecificationGuid],
                [PaymentSpecificationTypeId],
                [ExternalId],
                [Reference],
                [ExternalOriginatorId],
                [EventTimestamp],
                [Created]
            )
            VALUES 
            (
                @CurrencyBalanceId,
                @PaymentSpecificationGuid,
                @PaymentSpecificationTypeId,
                @ExternalId,
                @Reference,
                @ExternalOriginatorId,
                @EventTimestamp,
                @Created
            )
            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS Results;
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0              
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION             
                
        DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int              
        SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),              
        @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()              
              
        RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)              

    END CATCH
    
    
END
GO
```

thanks

Comment: I did not downvote, but code review questions should likely be submitted to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Which dbms? The above code is product specific.